# Show that the function $f(x)= \arcsin(x)$ is Lipschitz on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Actually , it is easy to see that$ f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[-1,1]$ , but via it's graph , I am sure that it's Lipschitz but I am unable to prove it . To show  for any x in [-1,1] ,    $$|\arcsin(x+c) - \arcsin(x)| < K.c$$ where $K >0$ for any $0< c < 2$

Comment: "I am sure that it's Lipschitz but I am disable to prove it" It is odd that you are sure it is and very comforting that you are unable to prove it is... What is the behaviour of $f(x)$ near $x=1$ already? Of course $f(1)=\pi/2$, but $f(1-\epsilon)$ is roughly... what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{d}{dx}\mbox{arcsin}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ blows up as $x$ gets close to $\pm 1$, which means it could not possibly be Lipschitz on $[-1,1]$, as Lipschitz functions must have bounded derivatives whenever they exist. As an analogous example, consider $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ near $x=0$, which is again not Lipschitz.

Comment: @GonzaloBenavides: A Lipschitz function *must* have a bounded derivative wherever it exists. This follows straight from definitions: $\lim_{x\rightarrow y} \left|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\right|\leq L$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that for $0<\varepsilon<1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\left|\arcsin(1)-\arcsin(1-\varepsilon)\right|&=\left|\int_{1-\varepsilon}^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt\right|\\\\
&\ge\frac12\int_{1-\varepsilon}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}\,dt\\\\
&=\sqrt\varepsilon
\end{align}$$

Can you conclude now?